# How to repeat function inside the same function?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

First I loop through an array in function(a) and add event listeners to all the array items. Then, when an event is clicked, I run function(b), and then i want to re-add that event listener that was clicked, so I can repeat function(b) again if the same array item is clicked.

```
Array.forEach(function(a) {
a.addEventListener("click", function(b) {
    if ( 1 == 1){
        //some code//
        a.addEventListener("click", ***???*** )
    }
}) 
});
```

I put ***???*** where I think the solution is, but obviously I am not sure.

EDIT 11.45;

```
let days = document.getElementsByClassName("day");
let daysArray = Array.from(days);

daysArray.forEach(function(current) {
current.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (current.classList.contains("purpleHover")){
        current.classList.remove("purpleHover")
        current.classList.add("correct")
        current.addEventListener("click", this())
    }
    else{
        current.classList.add("purpleHover")
        current.classList.remove("correct")
    }
});
})
```

Comment: Usually when you want to reuse a function, you give it a name and use that name. But why do you want to _re-add_ the event listener?

Comment: I want to re-add the event listener because it going to be clicked multiple times. But when it has fired once, it’s gone and nothing happen when it gets clicked again.

Comment: @Dave that's not the default behaviour of `addEventListener()`, so there should be no need to re-add it. Can you create a [mre] to show your issue

Comment: _"But when it has fired once, it’s gone"_ Then you're doing something else in your code that you're not telling us about. Like replacing the HTML, or something like that. Please do create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My bad, i didnt know. I updated it now.

Comment: @Dave The button can still be clicked even after it has been clicked once (currently your attempt to make it clickable again will make throw an error, which might make it seem like it's not working). Please create a runnable example of your issue, this cannot be reproduced: https://jsfiddle.net/wm0a1opx/

Comment: Hey. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I found the problem, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

By default when you addEventListener, it'll be invoked for each event, unless you specify the option `once` to be true, therefore your code should just be :

```js
Array.forEach(function(a) {
  a.addEventListener("click", function(b) {
        //some code//
  }) 
});
```